# How to install, configure and Start Wraith BBC?

Tags: ruby, windows, phantomjs

I'm trying install Wraith from https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith  And i don't succeed.

on CMD command, i'm trying :

```
start ruby 
start phantomjs
rake c:\ruby\bin\wraith-master
```

And this snap a single image....

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

So, after, i'm trying :

```
rspec
```

But it doesn't work...and display :

```
F.......................
```

In fact, i have installed Ruby, Phamtonjs and Wraith in the same repository.

Now, i would like start the script which snap

2 images and compare them ....

Can you help me or tell me the steps to succeed?

Thank you Very Much !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider running Linux on your Windows in a virtual box!

Then you will find an easy install guide here:

https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/visual-diff-with-wraith/

If you need to rely on windows check this guide:
[How to install wraith on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245304/how-to-install-wraith-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us which OS you're trying to run this under. As for myself on MacOSX; this video went a long way towards orienting myself in the process: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE_19L0l2q0