# How to install wraith on windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, phantomjs, slimerjs

Does anyone knows (maybe all relevant steps) how I can run/install Wraith on Windows 7?

The documentation (http://bbc-news.github.io/wraith/index.html#Installation) is unfortunately very vague.

Thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required downloads:

- https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip
- http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p481.exe?direct
- http://cdn.rubyinstaller.org/archives/devkits/DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe
- http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.9-1-Q16-x64-dll.exe
- https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith/archive/master.zip

Installation:

- Install ImageMagick
- Unpack PhantomJs in various folder
- Install Ruby by use of RubyInstaller
- Unpack Ruby DevKit
- Unpack Wraith to some folder

PATH-Variables:

- \ImageMagick
- \PhantomJs
- \Ruby200\bin

Command-Line:

- go to Wraith-folder
- call "gem install wraith"
- call "wraith setup"
- enjoy wraith

The configuration can be changed in the file config.yaml